# jQuery AJAX CORS request fails when sent with headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cors

I am sending an AJAX request with jQuery using this code:

```
$.ajax({
url: url + "MemberIds/" + $("#username").val(),
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: true,
success: function( jsonObj ) {
        console.log( jsonObj );
    }
```

});

This works fine. But if I add headers to the request, it fails:

```
$.ajax({
url: url + "Members/" + $.session.get("userid") + "/ProjectSpaces",
dataType: "json",
crossDomain: true,

headers:{
    "x-proom-credentials": $.session.get("authheader")
},
success: function(jsonObj) {
    console.log(jsonObj);
    }
});
```

The preflight returns with 200 OK:

```
Response Headers
    Access-Control-Allow-Headers:x-proom-credentials, accept, origin
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*
    Connection:keep-alive
    Content-Length:0
    Server:Bogus
```

But the actual request shows up as cancelled.

Comment: are you running this locally?

Answer (score 0):

You must be running it locally